# Deployment Exception with Java -> Glassfish

Tags: java, exception, deployment, glassfish

I've got a Problem with Deploying my Code on my Glassfish Server. When trying to deploy I get this four Exceptions:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class sun.security.provider.SunEntries from class com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityLifecycle errors were found
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityLifecycle
```

I am using Java SDK 1.8.0_322 and GlassFish 5.0.1.

My Code:

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/hello-world")
public class HelloResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

my Pom File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If there is more Code you need pls, just ask. I am fairly new to this and so I dont know if I missed something basic/important.

From what I am reading out of this Exceptions he is trying to access/write in a File that is not Included? But where is this needed and why?